# JasperReports - Conditional style per locale?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way to use a different styles, or redefine a style, based on a report parameter locale? I need to modify font sizes for certain languages.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this in the past using external style templates. There is a [sample on jasperforge](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/templates/index.html) that illustrates how to do this.

Once you've moved your styles to external templates, you can create locale specific templates. The templating mechanism allows you to inherit from and override specific styles, so the locale specific versions don't get overly bloated. The example I linked above includes inheriting from and overriding base styles.

In your reports, you can then load the appropriate template at render time.

One easy way to do this is:

- provide the path to the template that you want to use as a parameter
  to the report
- include a template tag in the jrxml file that references the
  parameter:

  <template><![CDATA[$P{TEMPLATE_PATH}]]></template>

Then, in the code that renders the report, just set the TEMPLATE_PATH parameter appropriately for the report locale.

Again, the linked documentation mentions how to do this.

Comment: Within the report, how can you determine the current report locale?

Comment: There is a built in parameter called REPORT_LOCALE that should be set by the renderer of the report - if run from iReport, this can be set under report execution options, if you are rendering from Java code, this is normally done by doing something like : metadata.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale); Where metadata is the parameter map sent to fillReport